# How to convert an Element to a Method?

Tags: java, reflection, annotation-processing

I'm building an annotation processor for an annotation called "Auditable". The processor gets invoked by the builder (some parts are left out for easier reading):

```
@Override
public boolean process( Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
        RoundEnvironment roundEnv ) {

    //--- Obtain all annotated elements
    Set<? extends Element> annotatedElements =
            roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith( Auditable.class );

    //--- Separate elements into classes, fields and methods
    for ( Element element : annotatedElements ) {
        ElementKind kind = element.getKind();
        if ( ElementKind.METHOD.equals( kind ) ) {
            checkAndAddMethod( element );  // <-- Must convert Element to Method
        } 
    ... }

void checkAndAddMethod( Method method ) {  // <-- parameter type = Method
```

How can I convert the annotated `Element` to a `Method`?

Comment: I don't think you can, because the language model represents code, and reflection represents the running JVM. Can you perhaps work with `ExecutableElement` instead? That represents a method, constructor or initializer as part of the language model.

Comment: You are right and thanks for the hint "model versus runtime reflection". `ExecutableElement` works for this. I would accept this as an answer.

Comment: I've posted it as an answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can, because the language model represents code, and reflection represents the running JVM. Can you perhaps work with `ExecutableElement` instead? That represents a method, constructor or initializer as part of the language model.

Answer (score -1):

If an annotation has enough data like class name, method name, and arguments etc., then the below snippet can get you a Method object.

```
String className = // Get from the annotation attribute
String argumentClassName = // Get from the annotation attribute
String methodName = // Get from the annotation attribute

Class myClass = Class.forName(className);
Class argumentClass = Class.forName(argumentClassName);
Method method = myClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, argumentClass);
```

Refer this [link1](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2014/08/invoke-method-using-method-object.html), [link2](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2014/08/invoke-static-methods-using-reflection.html) for an example.

Comment: Classes that are currently compiled won't be loaded in the compiling JVM.